# Google chart from python dataframe Fails to draw

Tags: javascript, html, flask, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to send a pandas dataframe as json through flask. Then I want to plot it in html using google chart. But I am not able to build the Datatable correctly, so chart shows like 'No Table Columns'. Please help to draw the graph.

python part :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
return df.to_json()
```

javascript part :

```
value = get_data();
drawing = new google.visualization.DataTable(value);
chart.draw(drawing , options);
```

Please help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

when creating google's data table directly from json,

```
drawing = new google.visualization.DataTable(value);
```

the json must be in a very specific format, as found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)...

instead, try using the static method --> `arrayToDataTable`

this will create a data table from a simple array...

```
drawing = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have tried this earlier. But the conversion was not accepted.

Comment: in the javascript, will you please share a sample of the following? --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(value));`